# wavelike properties of massive objects

Tags: waves

I have learned in my HS physics 2 class that everything with mass has a wavelength given by the deBroglie wavelength. My question is : Does this mean that any object can show diffraction, such as in the Davisson-Germer experiment showing the diffraction of electrons? Does this also mean that objects may display different properties of a wave too? (Refraction/reflection)

Comment: See also [Why doesn't a marble rolling on a table ever reflect back at the edge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56705/why-doesnt-a-marble-rolling-on-a-table-ever-reflect-back-at-the-edge). I'm sure there are other related questions, but these are the two I remember.

Comment: Thank you I'm currently on a phone and cannot easily search duplicates. It was more or less the same question