# What is the probability of a person quantum tunneling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

I understand that it has been shown that small particles can quantum tunnel to just about anywhere in space (with decreasing probability the further out they go) since they all act as waves when they are not being observed and propagate outward across the universe. (Please correct me if I am wrong about any of that.)

Since we are made exclusively out of these same particles, does this mean that there is a non-zero probability that all of my particles will quantum tunnel at once tonight and I will wake up on the moon tomorrow?

If so, how can I find that probability?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327220/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67628/,

Comment: You can't tunnel to the Moon because the potential energy of you on the Moon is higher than here on Earth. You can tunnel to the Sun, so there is an astronomically small probability of you ending up in the Sun and dying instantly there. On the other hand, there is also an astronomically  small probability of you arising spontaneously out of thin air at some random place in the universe.  So, you can then appear on the Moon after all, but that's then without you vanishing from the Earth.

Comment: Probability means nothing. When an improbable thing happens to people, do they care how low the probability was? No, it's already happened. So you should be well prepared for waking up on the Moon any day now.