# Touching is a Pauli exclusion principle or electrostatic force?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

According to quantum field theory touching is an electrostatic repulsion between electrons or the Pauli exclusion principle? How can physicists distinguish these two phenomena if they give the same effect?

Comment: The Pauli exclusion principle isn't exactly a force.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: "How can I stand on the ground? EM or/and Pauli?" (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1077)