# How non-collinear forces balance each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, statics, moment

In the system of parallel forces , all the forces are non-colinear. So how to they balance each other?.[image]

Here in this case a wooden plank is supported at its end by two supports. All the forces here are non-colinear.
So how do the tension in that supports balance the weight of plank?

And if they balance each other , then why the equal and opposite forces in couple don't balance?

I don't understand principal of moments intuitively.

So , do explain

Comment: Colinear forces are the most trivial case to avoid avoid twisting. The example of the picture shows that it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the plank to be in equilibrium, the sum of the vertical forces must be zero and the sum of the moments about any point on the plank must be zero. There are no horizontal forces.

This means the sum of the upward reaction forces at A and B must equal the sum of the downward applied forces at D and C, and the clockwise moments about any point must equal the counterclockwise moments about the same point.

For example the clockwise moments about A due to downward forces C and D must equal the counterclockwise moment about A due to the upward reaction force at B. That will be the case if the distance between C and D is 1 meter (it isn't shown in the diagram)

> I don't understand principal of moments intuitively.

Think about a moment or torque as being the turning effect about a point due to the application of a force. An example is using a wrench to turn a bolt. You apply a force perpendicular to the arm of the wrench. The moment or torque is the product of your applied force and the length of the arm of the wrench between the bolt and the point where you apply the force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't equal and opposite forces in couple balance each other?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709468/how-the-object-rotates . Would you pls answer this question?

Comment: Let’s do one question At a time. When you say “couple” are you referring to a “force couple”?

Comment: Yes , two equal and opposite unlike parallel forces acting on two different point on a single object.

Comment: What do you mean by “ unlike “?

Comment: Force which are in opposite direction but parallel to each other

Comment: OK we have that straight. In any event the forces in a couple only "cancel" each other with respect to translational (linear) acceleration of the center of mass of the object. But unless they are countered with another opposite couple, they will cause rotational (angular) acceleration. In any event, what does a force couple have to do with your plank example? There are no force couples in your example.

Comment: "And if they balance each other , then why the equal and opposite forces in couple don't balance?" . This what I am asking

Comment: Can’t you see that they will cause rotation?

Comment: physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709468/… . Would you pls answer this question?

Comment: That question has nothing to do with couples. Sorry but I can’t help you