# Is the Pauli Exclusion Principle the Cause of Normal Force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, pauli-exclusion-principle

I'm currently studying about Dynamics in my physics class. I was looking up where the normal force comes from, and I thought that the normal force comes from Newton's third law. However, going through the internet I've seen that Newton's third law actually doesn't apply to the normal force, and it actually is caused by the Pauli exclusion principle. I was wondering if the Pauli exclusion principle is the only cause for normal force? And why is it the cause of normal force?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1077/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thank you! @Qmechanic

Comment: Newton's third law applies to the normal force. If you push on a wall then the wall pushes back on you.